# color2D.matplot Legend in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to change the placement of the legend in color2D.matplot (plotrix)? I have a12 x 12 correlation matrix. I noticed I had to reverse the row names and change the margin to get the long names to fit. But now I am stumped on how to move the legend (without increasing the margin even more and making the graph look odd with so much white space at the bottom. Thanks!

```
cors<-cor(train)cellcol<-color.scale(cbind(cors,c(-1,rep(1,11))),c(0,1),0,c(1,0))[,1:12]
par(mar = c(10,8,4,2) + 0.1)
color2D.matplot(cors,cellcolors=cellcol,show.legend=TRUE,show.values=2,
  axes=FALSE, xlab="",ylab="")
axis(1,at=0.5:11.5,las=2,labels=colnames(cors))
axis(2,at=0.5:11.5,las=2,labels=rev(rownames(cors)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The help page says:
"If the default is not suitable, call color.legend separately."  And then gives an example.

Based on a guess (in the absence of any information about "train" or "cors", you can try:

```
color.legend(0,13,6.5,14,legend=c(-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1),
   rect.col=color.scale(cbind(cors,c(-1,rep(1,11))),c(0,1),0,c(1,0))[,1:12], 
   align="rb")
```

Comment: I read through the help pages, but being completely new to R graphics (and this package specifically) I was unable to figure out how to do it. Thus I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction with a code snippet.

Comment: I pointed you to an example on the help page. Your "train" data is not available, so I don't know its structure and your code does not run. Based on a guess as to the user coordinates I will add an EDIT.